# Python - How do I convert a a string containing more than one number to an int?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

How can I convert a string containing more than one number to an int in python, for example: `"100, 200, 300"` and `"400, 500"`. I know how I can convert a string containing a single number such as `"100"` or `"56"` to an int but not a string which contains 2 numbers.

Does anyone know how this could be done?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Using [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) for mapping list element to `int`

```
x = "100, 200, 300"
list(map(int, x.split(",")))
```

Output:

```
[100, 200, 300]
```

Comment: But you need to be sure that substrings are integers, otherwise you'll get ValueError.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [list comprehensions](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_list_comprehension.php):

```
In [635]: x = "100, 200, 300"
In [638]: results = [int(i) for i in x.split(',')]

In [639]: results
Out[639]: [100, 200, 300]
```